# Detect a change in fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

How can i detect a change in fragment for a container?

i am using a bottom navigation view in my app and have mutiple fragments that my user switches through and they are all displayed in one container. i want to detect a change in the fragment so i can change different properties of the toolbars for each fragments and control whether the bottom navigation is visible.

this is the code i was thinking of using and just calling the method at the transition, but it does not currently work as i am getting null reference exception for the bottomNavigation and suppoortActionBar.

```
    public void ChangeInFragment(string fragment)
    {
        bool IsMain = true;

        switch (fragment)
        {
            case "homefrg" :
                IsMain = true;
                break;

            case "favfrg" :
                IsMain = true;
                break;

            case "morefrg":
                IsMain = true;
                break;

            case "splitfrg":
                IsMain = false;
                break;

            case "wattfrg":
                IsMain = false;
                break;

            case "weightfrg":
                IsMain = false;
                break;
        }

        if(IsMain == true)
        {
            bottomNavigation.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            bottomNavigation.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

this probably isnt the best way to do it but if there is no way to detect a change in fragment could someone explain why the bottom nav and toolbar are returning null?

Thanks

Comment: I would assume that the fragments are outside the view and are `destroyed` and are `null`. How will you detect the "change" in your fragments? In one way or another you need to connect your fragments and the bottombar.

Comment: This is inside the main activity and i will just call this method before a transaction thats why im looking for a proper way to do it.

Comment: So my understanding tells me all you want is which fragment is currently loaded on the screen right?

Comment: yes i would like to know that but my main focus is to detec an change in fragment @G.hakim

Comment: So how exactly do you plan on detecting this i mean at which event?

Comment: @G.hakim thats what im wondering if there is a way to do that? for the back button on the toolbar and the bottom navigation view im currently having to to run a method in the main activity as i couldnt get the back button a a toolbar to work in a fragment

Comment: I can give you a solution to get the current displayed fragment name if you call that function you will be able to know which fragment is on display

Answer (score 0):

All this function needs is your current activity instance to get the current fragment

```
 public Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetVisibleFragment(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity)
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager = appCompatActivity.SupportFragmentManager;
        IList<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.Fragments;
        if (fragments != null)
        {
            foreach (Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment in fragments)
            {
                if (fragment != null && fragment.IsVisible)
                    return fragment;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for spending your time on this but i found i work around that seems to be working just fine